# NSMutableString not inserting the string at specified position

Tags: objective-c

I have a NSString object "testtimeFrame" which i am converting to NSMutableString object "mutable" and doing insertStringAtIndex method..
my testtimeframe value is 05-8-2012 and i want to insert "0" before 8 but it's showing it as 80 instead of 08..

```
NSMutableString * mutable = [NSMutableString stringWithString:testtimeFrame];
[mutable insertString:@"0" atIndex:3];
NSLog(@"my day is:%@",mutable);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct behavior. Remember that index always starts at 0!

```
0: 0
1: 5
2: -
3: 8
```

So your code is fine! I've just run:

```
NSMutableString * mutable = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"05-8-2012"];
[mutable insertString:@"0" atIndex:3];
NSLog(@"my day is:%@",mutable);
```

And it works great!

You probably have a problem with: `testtimeframe`

Comment: thanks for the reply but i have checked with the above code but it's still printing 80 for me even if i am hardcoding it as you posted @"05-8-2012"

Comment: I can copy and paste the exact code from here and it produces the expected output of `05-08-2012`. Are you saying if you copy and paste this exact code (including the hard coded string) that it doesn't work for you?

Comment: even if i use index 1 or 2 it's still printing it as 80 only…

Comment: ya i am copying and pasting the same code as posted by you but not getting as 08…i am using xcode 4.0.1

Comment: Try creating a brand new, empty project and then copy & paste this code.

Comment: don't know why it happened but when i restarted my xcode and then cleaned the project it's working fine…the hardcoded one also and the testtimeframe also..

Comment: now i got that as 08..now i want to compare that with an array which stores the value say 3,10,17,24 how can i know in which range it's falling?i mean 6 falls between 3 and 10 of this array..how can i check that because based on that i need to select the nearest value..in this case 3

Comment: Ask a new question, becouse there is no place here to answer you on that. And please tell us more. I don't completely understand what are you up to? Are you placing 8 in correct range or maybe you want to count it (like 6).

Comment: actually i have populated one picker dynamically (two other pickers are populated with month and years)from an array as all the sundays of a month..so when the view appears i want to select current month and year and sunday…month and year i have done…but the thing is for the sunday picker i need to select the nearest sunday value if today is not sunday….actually the above question which i asked from that i got the day value….suppose in this case today is 8th and my sunday picker shows me 6,13,20,27(may,2012 sundays) so i need to select 6 because it's the nearest sunday from today

Comment: i am storing the day value as a string(myday)from the above mutable string mutable..here it's 08 so i now need to compare it with the values from the sunday array(suppose 6,13,20,27) and want to replace it with the value nearest to 08...    myday= [mutable substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 2)];

Answer (score -1):

The obvious solution would be to give it an index of 2 instead of 3.

That said, the documentation for the `insertString:atIndex` method make it sound like your original code should have worked:

> The new characters begin at anIndex and the existing characters from
>   anIndex to the end are shifted by the length of aString.

Since the '8' character was at index 3, it sounds like your 0 should have been placed there and the 8 shifted one place to the right, producing the desired '08'

Comment: -1 index at 3 will result in 05-08-2012 and index at 2 will result in 050-8-2012

Comment: @Jennis I know that is the expected behavior (hence why I quoted the documentation), but originally the question essentially stated that the 0 character was appearing one spot too far to the right, so I threw out the obvious solution of moving the index one place to the left.